# Schedule a Scan in Backup Exec 12.5

Tags: backupexec

Is there a way to schedule a "Scan" in Backup Exec to find out what tapes are available by barcode? Or do i have to schedule an inventory instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't schedule a scan in Backup Exec, nor is it available through the *bemcmd.exe* command line utility.  The only other option is to schedule an inventory of the library.  To do this, go to the *Devices* tab and right-click on the library, then go to *Schedule* and change it to *"Run according to schedule"*.

The problem with doing an inventory versus scan is that it will take a long time and not take advantage of having a barcode reader.